# PHP vs Java Encryption key generation

Tags: java, php, encryption, openssl, aes

I feel like I have tried everything to get java to PHP using AES; however, I have found that the keys are not the same after I hashed them. I have kept the salt as a string because I couldn't get it to work with an empty byte array; however, it hasn't changed anything. I heard somewhere that dividing the key length by 8 is needed in PHP, so that's why I have it.

I know the hash functions to check for matching works as I have tested it with a random string, and they match up.

JAVA:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SecretKey secret = generateSecret("PASSWORD");
  System.out.println(hashString(new String(secret.getEncoded()));
}

public static SecretKey generateSecret(String password) throws Exception {
  //byte[] salt = new byte[8];
  byte[] salt = "SALT".getBytes("UTF-8");
  SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
  KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
  SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
  return new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
}

public static String hashString(String request) throws Exception {
  MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
  byte[] buffer = messageDigest.digest(request.getBytes());

  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(buffer.length * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    int v = buffer[i] & 0xff;
    if (v < 16) {
      sb.append('0');
    }
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
  }

  return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

PHP:

```php
$password = 'PASSWORD';

salt = 'SALT';//pack('nvc*', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

$bytes = derivateKey($password, $salt, 65536, 256);
echo hash('sha512', $bytes);

function derivateKey($password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits){
    return hash_pbkdf2('sha512', $password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits/8, true);
}
```

Java returns with this hash:

> 9E6B73EA6FA176F8D0651AC4DA73F0CEBE603DA6B31A226443CABBB80EDF51BCE663F92945F5DC1C0B8F0098DDE61C3117CCEDFEB7DB4A959315DE635BC7F1BB

php returns with this hash:

> 135d49502ca99da44f3050f37e7ca0e8ca16c18a9b3120c95bb8cf45e97c0120053c51a3f134fbf38c4105186362086e9504a130dc3ad5633c9968f2b12c1ac6

Comment: The results of both codes are identical. What is the problem?

Comment: The hashes dont match what so ever. Therefore I cannot encrypt or decrypt anything.

Comment: I can' t reproduce that. Please post your results of both codes.

Comment: I added the hash results from both

Comment: In the Java code please define the encoding to be used (in all `new String()` and `getBytes()` methods).

Comment: I am just using new String() and getBytes() I assume thats just going to use UTF-8

Comment: If no encoding is defined, the default encoding is used.

Comment: You convert the PBKDF2 result to a string with a charset encoding: `hashString(new String(secret.getEncoded())`. This generally corrupts the data and is probably at least one of the problems.

Comment: Wow, I think your right, I tried it with a base64 encoding and they matched, I appreciate the help. Sometimes its the dumb stuff that gets me haha.

Comment: For me the `hashString` is not well defined either way, especially as public function. First of all, it is "stringly typed", which is just unnecessary. But even if we allowed that, then you should specify an encoding for the input parameter and put at least "hex" somewhere in the name, because there is no specific encoding for a hash function (hex has become some kind of defacto standard, but this is not according to some kind of spec, and comparing lower & uppercase hex is also tricky).